# SQL Function that uses a time-stamp to output how old a question is

Tags: sql, mysql, timestamp, calculated-field

I have a calculated field whose value I want to modify depending on how old the entry is. Is there way in MySQL to take a time stamp and use it to determine how old a query is.

Here is the calculated field

```
((ces.EXPERT_SCORE * cirm.CONSUMER_RATING) + (12.5 * scs.SIMILARITY)* (1 - EXP(-0.5 * (cal.TIPS_AMOUNT / ATV.AVG_TIPS)) + .15))AS ANSWER_SCORE
```

Basically, I want to multply this calculated field based on the age of a timestamp.

Comment: Are you asking for a 1d3h52m kind of output?

Comment: Ideally, I get the age in seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can trivially convert a MySQL date/datetime field to an integer with `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`, which'll give you the oldschool signed 32bit integer where 0 represents Jan 1/1970.

Comment: But with MySQL, there is no advantage to using an integer over the native date/time types.

Comment: No, but you can't do things like "SELECT distance / duration FROM table" and get a velocity from the query. Hence converting the date/time fields into a plain integer.